# Cannot track down source of entry in Mac OSx PATH variable

Tags: macos, path

I find these entries in my PATH when I type

```
echo $PATH

/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I opened /etc/paths and found them there. I deleted them from /etc/paths.
I closed terminal and reopened it but they are still present when typing

echo $PATH

Where are they coming from?

Comment: You want to remove them? I would be surprised if stuff does not break.

Comment: I am just trying to find all the places Mac OSX looks to construct the path.